# Oracle update statement in java

Tags: java, oracle

This is my code for the `Oracle database` to update a record I have done insert delete and search but fail to update.  Kindly suggest to me what's wrong in the code or in the query.

```
Statement stmt;
try {
    stmt = DBPRoject.conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("update personinfo set cnic='"+CnicNo+"','name="+name+"','login="+login+"','password="+psd+"','zip="+Zip+"','persontypeid="+typeid+"' where cnic="+CnicNo);
    //stmt.executeQuery("update  personinfo set cnic=" + '"+CnicNo+"', '"+name+"', '"+login+"', '"+psd+"', '"+Zip+"',+typeid+);
    stmt.executeQuery("commit");
    stmt.executeQuery("update  personcont set cnic='"+CnicNo+", 'address="+HomeAdd+"', 'city="+City+"', 'statep="+State+"', 'mobno="+MobNo+"','email="+Email+"','nationality="+Nationality+"','persontypeid"+typeid+"','status"+Status+"' where cnic="+CnicNo);
    stmt.executeQuery("commit");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated sucessfully"); 

}
catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException uni){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Uniqe CNIC");
    return;
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Add_Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I am stuck at this point need some help :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is you seem to be quoting the column name and value for some of your constraints...

```
 ...'name="+name+"','login="+login+"','password="+psd+"','zip="+Zip+"','persontypeid="+typeid+"' ...
    ^-------------^ ^---------------^ ^----------------^ ^-----------^ ^-----------------------^
```

The second issues is, you shoud be using [`PreparedStament`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to reduce the risk of SQL injection

For example...

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("update personinfo set cnic=?,name=?,login=?,password=?,zip=?,persontypeid=? where cnic=?")) {
    stmt.setString(1, CnicNo);
    stmt.setString(2, name);
    stmt.setString(3, login);
    stmt.setString(4, psd);
    stmt.setString(5, Zip);
    stmt.setString(6, typeid);
    stmt.setString(7, CnicNo);
    int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Also, assuming that `autoCommit` is set to `false` for the `Connection`, you should simply be able to use `con.commit();` to commit the updates instead of executing another query, but this might be a particular requirement of the driver

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, as you have not provided error message and the content of your variables is not given but you are setting **'** before the name of some attributes, e.g `'name="+name+"'` could result for example into `'name=John'`, but the correct syntax is `name='John'` so just correct this on all of the places you do that. Then make sure that you are not quoting integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the final SQL statement in to log and check for error. Change `'name="+name+"'` into `name='"+name+"'` for all other fields.